# Linking HTML5 audio that plays to an svg for mute on/off?

Tags: javascript, button, audio, svg, mute

To me, this seems quite complicated to a new developer. However...

I am trying to link and audio tag that automatically plays an mp3 track (no controls) to an SVG button that I made.

Let me tell you about the SVG..

The SVG is a audio/wave and when you click it, it turns into a circle. I guess technically it is not a button but an image that when you click changes (swaps).

What I want it to do is when the audio plays I want the SVG to show the audio symbol, and when you click the svg I want any audio to be muted and the svg to be showing the circle.

Thank you in advance.

```
<style>
#muteButton {
    position:fixed;
    top:600px;
    right:60px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;

}
</style>

<svg id="muteButton" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 234.35 264.21">
<style>.audioOnOff{fill:none;stroke:#111;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:20px;}</style>
<title>mutEBUTTON</title>
<defs>
<g id="audioOnIcon">
<path id="path1" class="audioOnOff" d="M69.68,189.27A107.07,107.07,0,0,0,86,132.46a107.13,107.13,0,0,0-16.78-57.6"/>
<path id="path1-2" data-name="path1" class="audioOnOff" d="M36,161.45a54.93,54.93,0,0,0,8.38-29.15,55,55,0,0,0-8.61-29.55"/>
<path id="path2" class="audioOnOff" d="M106.77,37.31a159.25,159.25,0,0,1,31.38,95.15,159.09,159.09,0,0,1-30.87,94.39"/>
<path id="path1-3" data-name="path1" class="audioOnOff" d="M142.12,261.71A207.74,207.74,0,0,0,187,132.46a207.83,207.83,0,0,0-45.43-130"/>
</g>
<circle id="audioOffIcon" class="audioOnOff" cx="117.17" cy="130.11" r="114.67"/>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#audioOnIcon" pointer-events="all" onclick="this.href.baseVal = this.href.baseVal == '#audioOnIcon' ? '#audioOffIcon' : '#audioOnIcon';"/>
</svg>



   <audio autoplay src="../Assests/Audio/Minimal Piano Dreams -[ mymp3download.net ].mp3" type="mpeg"></audio>
```